# Reading all values that are left and right to <= from a big string in python

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, substring

I have a big string , and want o read all values that are left and right to <= for e.g `{\nnode [shape=box] ;\n0 [label="X[2] <= 17055.5\\ngini = 0.0454\\nsamples = 43\\nvalue = [42, 1]"] ;\n1 [label="gini = 0.0\\nsamples = 1\\nvalue = [0, 1]"] ;\n0 -> 1 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=45, headlabel="True"] ;\n2 [label="gini = 0.0\\nsamples = 42\\nvalue = [42, 0]"] ;\n0 -> 2 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=-45, headlabel="False"] [label]="X[0] <= 5.41" ;\n}` Here I should have two set of outputs , because <= appears twice

python regex python-3.x

Comment: Whats your expected output from the input?

Comment: @heemayl this is the question

Comment: x[2] <= 17055.5 and x[0] <= 5.41

Comment: Hold on, so you basically want to split the whole string on the `=>`? Have you tried `re.split()`? Also, it's nice to show what have you tried already, and why it's not working.

Comment: I see , in place of <= when using re.split().

Comment: I was trying to implement using  dictionary in loop since long, because regex appears intimidating i wanted to avoid it. :(

Comment: And what would you want to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you want words around `<=` that are delimited by either `"` or `\`. If so:

```
re.findall(r'["\\]([^"\\]+<=[^"\\]+)(?=["\\])', str_)
```

- `["\\]` matches `"` or `\`
- The captured group, `([^"\\]+<=[^"\\]+)`, matches one or more characters that are not `"` or `\`, followed by `<=`, then again one or more characters that are not `"` or `\`
- Zero with positive lookahead, `(?=["\\])`, ensures the captured group is followed by either `"` or `\`

**Example:**

```
In [171]: str_ = '{\nnode [shape=box] ;\n0 [label="X[2] <= 17055.5\\ngini = 0.0454\\nsamples = 43\\nvalue = [42, 1]"] ;\n1 [label="gini = 0.0\\nsamples = 1\\nvalue = [0, 1]"] ;\n0 -> 1 [labeldistance=2.5,
     ...:  labelangle=45, headlabel="True"] ;\n2 [label="gini = 0.0\\nsamples = 42\\nvalue = [42, 0]"] ;\n0 -> 2 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=-45, headlabel="False"] [label]="X[0] <= 5.41" ;\n}'

In [172]: re.findall(r'["\\]([^"\\]+<=[^"\\]+)(?=["\\])', str_)
Out[172]: ['X[2] <= 17055.5', 'X[0] <= 5.41']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this one:

```
[^\"<]+<=\s*[0-9.]*
```

It probably can be faster, but it does the job.

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/RtC0A0/6/)